# How can I automatically open file selection rather than pressing the upload button?

Tags: javascript, html, input

How can I automatically open file selection rather than pressing the upload button?

```
<input type="file" id="upload_image" name="upload_image[]" style="display:none" multiple/>
```

Comment: are you looking for drag and drop

Comment: Have you tried ```oninput``` and/or ```onchange```? (And are you aware of [```submit()```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)?)